# button not working with .show() and .hide() functions

Tags: jquery, forms, logic

I ve faced a problem which I have no idea the why ... so Im here..

http://www.agenciadefreela.com.br/testJquery.php

thats the page!

First, I have to choose the "tipo" ...
 if is foto, I have to fill the "nome" ... and then, the "ok" button will show up. Once clicked, it will submit the form. Working fine.

But, When I change the "tipo" to video, I have to choose between "arquivo" (portuguese word to file) or "vimeo/youtube" link ... 
If is file (and we have a albuns's name) the ok button will show up ... BUT ...ITS NOT WORKING.... when the button is clicked, nothing happens ...
Its the same when link has been choosen, and in this case, theres a link validator ...

any idea ?????

ps: do not click in the "data" field... I didnt upload the files, so, if u do it, you will get a javascript error !

thns !

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the console logs:

```
hiddenMsg is not defined
hiddenMsg();
```

If you post your code on jsfiddle we might help

Comment: nops... I just forgot to upload the file with the function hiddenMsg ... its not working not even with no this problem ....